# Set Audio for ImageClip using MoviePy

Tags: python, moviepy

I'm trying to turn a static png + audio into a video clip which I can then concatenate along with other video clips.

```
intro = ImageClip(r'D:\skrooby\Vanity\timestamp.png', duration=3)
intro.set_audio(r'D:\skrooby\introsong.mp3')
outro = ImageClip(r'D:\skrooby\Vanity\continue.png', duration=20)
outro.set_audio(r'D:\skrooby\outrosong.mp3')
```

While this did not raise any errors, the produced clip does not have any sound over the intro and outro sections. How can I play the audio (audio files have 3 and 20s durations correspondingly) over my images?

Comment: @TomBurrows, you were able to help me last time, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`set_audio` returns a copy of the clip. Do `intro = intro.set_audio(...)` instead.

The name is definitely confusing so in v2.0 it is being changed to `with_audio`: github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/1170

Comment: Thanks again! @TomBurrows. Appreciate the quick response!

Comment: Sorry, 1 more query... @TomBurrows

`intro = ImageClip(r'D:\skrooby\Vanity\timestamp.png', duration=3)

intro = intro.set_audio(r'D:\skrooby\introsong.mp3')
outro = ImageClip(r'D:\skrooby\Vanity\continue.png', duration=20)

outro = outro.set_audio(r'D:\skrooby\outrosong.mp3')

scaledclips.insert(0, intro)

scaledclips.insert(len(scaledclips), outro)`

is returning: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'...

Comment: You need to pass a clip object into `set_audio` not a string.

Comment: perfect, thankyou. Any way to reduce processing time? that simple 23 seconds of outro and into took like 3 minutes... @TomBurrows

Comment: Not really much that can be done about it at the moment.